# Coding a multiple operation calculator in using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, math, calculator

I'm trying to code a calculator where the user inputs two numbers and then selects an operation(+,-,/,*) to perform which should give them a result. I've run the code multiply times in glitch and I keep getting an error in my JS saying **'operation is not defined'**(referring to the if statement in the JS). Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here and what needs changing

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>CALCULATOR</title>

    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>


    First Number : <input type="numbers" id="fnum" /><br /><br />
    Second Number : <input type="numbers" id="snum" /><br /><br />

    Operation? :
    <select id="operation">
      <option value="add">+</option>
      <option value="subtract">-</option>
      <option value="divide">/</option>
      <option value="multiply">*</option> </select><br /><br />

    <input type="button" id="Submit" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()" />

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("fnum").value);
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("snum").value);

  if (operation == 1) {
    var answer = num1 + num2;
    return answer;
  }
  else if (operation == 2) {
    var answer = num1 - num2;
    return answer;
  }
  else if (operation == 3) {
    var answer = num1 / num2;
    return answer;
  }
  else {
    var answer = num1 * num2;
    return answer;
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't see `operation` declared anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared the operation variable in your js file. Add the following code to the js file:

```
var o= document.getElementById("#operation") 
var operation = o.options[o.selectedIndex].value

#if-else conditions
```